# Building basic javascript object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if it's because it's late or what, but I seem to be having a really difficult time tonight thinking through structuring a pretty basic object array and building it.

What I'm trying to do is gather a list of text field id's and put them into a group variable;

Example

```
groupA:{year, make, model}
groupB:{color,body}
```

I'm not sure how to structure my main group object. I'm not sure if it should be using an array or not. Below is my first attempt

```
group = {groupA:{"year","make","model","trim"},groupB:{"body","color","transmission"}}
```

I attempted building my group object like so, but I really feel I'm doing it all wrong.

```
  //Class variable
  Var group = {}

  //this method is called for every textfield
  selectGroup = function(spec) {
    //Group id is the group the field is assigned to, example groupA, or groupB
    var groupId = spec.groupId;

    //I'm checking to see if groupId exist in group object, otherwise I add it. 
    if (!group.hasOwnProperty(groupId)) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[groupId] = [];
        group = obj;
    }
    //spec.id is the field id, example make, model
    group[groupId].push(spec.id);
};
```

If anybody could help me fix this all up, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing a colon and using the wrong array char: `group = {groupA:["year","make","model","trim"],groupB:["body","color","transmission"]}`

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote that out quick, I guess what I'm asking is if group should be an array of groupA, groupB etc, or if group should be an object of nested objects

Comment: If you have {} you need `{"year":1998,"model":"Model A","trim":"Silver"}` and you need lowercase "v" in "var"

Comment: @mplungjan your first example appears to be the config I'm looking for, is my code building that object correctly or no?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Nah it wont work. You are reinitializing group for every text box with the line `var obj = {};`

Comment: Thanks guys, this is probably a good indication I need to give this up for the night lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRX8z/1/)

```
var group = {};

//this method is called for every textfield
selectGroup = function (spec) {
    //Group id is the group the field is assigned to, example groupA, or groupB
    var groupId = spec.groupId;

    //I'm checking to see if groupId exist in group object, otherwise I add it. 
    if (!group.hasOwnProperty(groupId)) {
        group[groupId] = [];
    }
    //spec.id is the field id, example make, model
    group[groupId].push(spec.id);
};
```

Comment: Excelent, thanks for taking the time to put this example together.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want output like this,

```
group = {groupA:["year","make","model","trim"] , groupB:["body","color","transmission"]},
```

You can do,

```
var group = {};

if (!group.hasOwnProperty(groupId)) {            
    group[groupId] = [];            
}        
group[groupId].push(spec.id);
```